# Content Type Title translate itself

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have I site in Drupal 8 and a content type named "Ενηλίκοι".

The content's type title "Ενήλικοι"  is shown on the front end. How can I tranaslate "Ενήλικοι" to "Adults" when I am viewing the site on the english language?

Edit: I noticed that there is an option for translation the content type title, but when I use it I get the error:

> The configuration objects have different language codes so they cannot
>   be translated:
>
> node.type.drastiriotites_enilikoi: el
>
> core.base_field_override.node.drastiriotites_enilikoi.title: en

Can somenone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Drupal.t](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/translation-api/overview#s-translation-in-javascript-files) function for such purpose.

Comment: Sosy dont understand how can I use thisfunction to translate the content type title. Shouldn't I first  record somewhere the content's type translation?

Comment: ahh.. I thought that you are looking for a way to translate content using JS. Well, after adding a translation, it should work well. This is some specific issue. You probably can check this (looks similar):
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226263/how-to-resolve-configuration-objects-lang-code-differences